# How can I change the "Read More" text for a post preview when using post.preview instead of post.get_preview in Timber?

Tags: wordpress, timber

Before Timber version 1.3.1, if you wanted to change the Read More text for a post preview, you could use `{{ post.get_preview(50, 'false', 'Keep Reading') }}`. This function has been deprecated and it is recommended to use `{{ post.preview }}`, but it doesn't seem to have the ability to filter the Read More text easily.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn’t seem easy, probably because it isn’t documented yet. But we’re working on it!

`{{ post.preview }}` returns a [`PostPreview`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-postpreview/) object, which is a **chainable** object. This means that you can change the output of the preview by **adding methods**.

In your example, when you want to change the read-more text:

```
{{ post.preview.read_more('More!') }}
```

If you’d also want to change the length to 10 words only, you could do something like this:

```
{{ post.preview.length(10).read_more('More!') }}
```

Comment: post.preview.length(10) only works if I add .force at the end.

Comment: .force at the end is vital!

Comment: Perfect! @MichelMoraes! Also to hide, we set false into parenthesis. Like that `{{post.preview.length(25).force.read_more(false)}}`